# How to prove the limit exists and is equal to 0, and how to show the inequality holds

Tags: calculus

how to show the limit exists and is equal to $0$ using Squeeze Theorem.
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x^ay^b}{x^8+y^8}$$

Suppose $a+b>8$, how to show the inequality holds.
$$-(|x|^{a+b-8} + |y|^{a+b-8}) \le \frac{x^ay^b}{x^8+y^8} \le |x|^{a+b-8} + |y|^{a+b-8} $$

My approach:
$$\frac{|x|^{a+b-8} +|y|^{a+b-8} (x^8+y^8)}{x^8+y^8}$$
$$=\frac{|x|^{a+b-8} +|y|^{a+b-8} + x^8|y|^{a+b-8}+y^8x^{a+b-8}}{x^8+y^8}$$
Now stuck in how to prove $$|x|^{a+b-8} +|y|^{a+b-8} + x^8|y|^{a+b-8} + y^8|x|^{a+b-8} > x^ay^b$$
If you have better approach please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assume $a,b\ge 0.$Let $m=\max\{|x|\,|y|\}.$ Then
$$|x|^a|y|^b\le m^{a+b}=m^{a+b-8}m^8\le m^{a+b-8}(x^8+y^8)$$
Hence $${|x|^a|y|^b\over x^8+y^8}\le m^{a+b-8}\le |x|^{a+b-8}+|y|^{a+b-8}$$